# Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata).Found: <map object at 0x123122100>

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was just checking on this [style-transfer](https://github.com/CortexFoundation/StyleTransferTrilogy/tree/master/keras_version) project and wanted to use demo3.py in the folder kerns_version to try the result using the model that the author gave in the link he provided (named g7.h5). However, when I run the program, it raised a ValueError like this:

```
 in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs
raise ValueError(f'Output tensors of a {cls_name} model must be '
ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <map object at 0x123122100>
```

I had to change a few things as I'm running the program on a m1 Mac. I really don't know how to deal with this problem. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This is just a guess, but the code may have been meant to be run on Python 2.x, where `map()` returns a dictionary. In Python 3 `map()` is lazy. You can address this by putting `dict(...)` around the `map(...)` to make a proper dictionary.

Comment: Sorry for just replying. I've tried your method, only getting the same error.

Comment: It means that output tensors of the model must come from a TensorFlow layer that uses the tf.keras Lambda Layer. Basically, the model should be defined in a way which is like this : `model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)`